# Use Rcpp::NumericVector::create(R_NegInf) as function argument in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I would like to set -Inf as the default value for a function argument in Rcpp. I tried the following which throws an error at execution:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test_cpp1(
    Rcpp::NumericVector x = Rcpp::NumericVector::create(R_NegInf))
{
    return x;
}

[R] test_cpp1()                     
Error in test_cpp1() : object 'R_NegInf' not found
```

A possible workaround is creating an overflow:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test_cpp2(
    Rcpp::NumericVector x = Rcpp::NumericVector::create(-1E+999))
{
    return x;
}

[R] test_cpp2()                                
[1] -Inf
```

This works but causes warnings on the compilation.
Is there a workaround without this hack?
Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:

Another example for clarification. This works perfectly fine:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test_cpp3(
    NumericVector x = NumericVector::create(1, 2, 3))
{
    return x;
}
```

But this does not:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test_cpp4(
    NumericVector x = NumericVector::create(R_NegInf, 2, 3))
{
    return x;
}
```

It throws the following error on execution:

```
[R] test_cpp4()                                                                                                                                       
Error in test_cpp4() : object 'R_NegInf' not found
```

I would expect it to return -Inf. I need this Vector x inside an Rcpp function for some compuations. It should contain -Inf on default. But the user should be able to pass any numeric vector he/she wants.

Comment: I think you are confusing the API -- if you can a single argument coercible to `int` it means 'size'.  Can you clarify is this a value you want to assign?  "Special status" can be signalled via `Rcpp::Nullable<T>` and there are answers here detailing its use (and Rcpp Gallery posts).

Comment: I really want to assign negative Infinity to this vector. It is done [here](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/240_na_nan_inf.html) for the v1 vector so I thought this should be also possible for a function argument.  Rcpp::NumericVector::create(0) for example works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you picked the wrong signature. Based on your follow-up comment, maybe this is what you are after: one `int` argument for `size`, a second `double` argument for default value to be assigned?

```
> cppFunction("NumericVector myvec(int n, double v) { \
                  return NumericVector(n, v); }")
> myvec(3, 1.23)
[1] 1.23 1.23 1.23
>
```

which works for all values that are a double:

```
> makevec(3, -Inf)
[1] -Inf -Inf -Inf
>
```

If the value is a constant, there are a few ways to do that too. Here is one:

```
> cppFunction("NumericVector makevec2(int n) { \
      double val = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); \
      return NumericVector(n, val); }")
> makevec2(3)
[1] -Inf -Inf -Inf
>
```

*Edit:* Your edit makes your question clearer, and you are still hitting a wall over R not being C++: *types matter* !! While `NumericVector::create(1, 2, 3)` works *with these values of type `integer`* you simply *cannot* simply stick a double in there and hope for the best. (Though this may have to do with the nature of the `#define` used here.)

*Edit 2:*  Maybe the error had to do with C-level `#define`.  We can stick a single `double`, including `-Inf`, into `create()` as well:

```
> cppFunction("NumericVector makevec3() { \  
      double val = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();\
      return NumericVector::create(val); }")
> makevec3()
[1] -Inf
>
```

Comment: This is not what I was after. In R, I would simply do: fun <- function(x = -Inf){return(x)}. And it will return -Inf when calling fun() and a vector c(1,2,3,) when calling fun(c(1,2,3)).

Comment: You still have not explained very well _what exactly_ you are currently struggling with.  Maybe my last edit helps, else may you can edit the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Dirk. I extended my question. Hopefully its a little bit clearer what I'm after. It's really just about setting the default value of a numericvector to -Inf.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hoped I could just put the -Inf in and "hope for the best". I  just tested NumericVector x = NumericVector::create(0, 1, 2.3) which is mixing integers with doubles and this works fine.

Comment: Well my last answer _does_ in fact "just stick inf in there" but is more careful about where it gets the value from.  Anyway, maybe you should focus less on `create()` which really an internal function and use the (more obvious ?) ways of creating a vector, and then assigning a value.  I do not think there will be a speed penalty to be concerned with.  If one approach does not work, it may pay to consider alternatives...